# using anova to compare two linear models of unequal sample size: error

Tags: r, regression, anova

Here is an example of what I want to do, with a randomly generated number set:

```
a <- runif(100, min =0.5, max=1);
b <- runif(100, min = 0, max =1);
c <- factor(rep(c("High", "Low", "High", "High"), times = 25));

df<-data.frame(a,b,c);

head(df)

 a          b           c    
1 0.9506028 0.84686708 High    
2 0.7296878 0.24566532  Low    
3 0.6208635 0.90166263 High    
4 0.9009880 0.98464187 High    
5 0.6032242 0.23613096 High    
6 0.5409369 0.06325577  Low
```

So what I want to do here is to create two separate linear models, one for subsetted data (c=="High", n=75), and another for subsetted data (c=="Low", n=25)........

...Then I want to run an anova to compare the linear models:

```
mod1<-lm(b~a, data=df, subset = c=="High")

mod2<-lm(b~a, data=df, subset = c=="Low")
```

Up to this point everything works great, but the next command:

```
anova(mod1,mod2)
```

Produces an error:

> Error in anova.lmlist(object, ...) : 
>         models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset

This issue may be solved using the update function, although I have yet to come across an example showing how to update the subset function within the lm call line.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

By following:

```
mod1<-lm(b~a, data=df, subset = c=="High")
mod2<-lm(b~a, data=df, subset = c=="Low")
```

You fit two models: 
$$Y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X +\epsilon$$
$$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X +\epsilon$$

These two models can be combined into one model:
$$Y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X + Z(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X) + \epsilon$$
where $Z=1$ for c="Low" and = 0 for c="High".

Then you can test the null hypothesis $\beta_0 = 0$ (two lines have the same intercepts) or $\beta_1 = 0$ (two lines have the same slope) or $\beta_0 = 0, \beta_1 = 0$ (two lines are totally the same).

I tried following, and it works.

```
  cmod<-lm(b~a*factor(c), data=df)
```